# SSRS report in iframe appears then disappears

Tags: html, iframe, reporting-services

I am using an iframe to show an SSRS report and I am experiencing a strange problem. When I attempt to present a report that contains nothing by a chart everything works perfectly, but when I attempt to show a report that contains a list of customers the content appears then disappears right after loading.

The main difference is that the chart report is by SSRS stored as an image converted to binary data in the database, while the customer list report is by SSRS stored as text data converted to binary data in the database. The customer list report is rendered as a lot of different JavaScript functions and HTML code, while the chart report is rendered as a lot of different JavaScript functions and some HTML code to present the final chart image.

I just cannot get my head around why this should crash. I would have thought that it would be completely safe HTML-wise to render a complete HTML document in an iframe. Does anyone have any clue as to why the list report first appears then all of a sudden disappears again when the chart report works perfectly?

EDIT: I am only experiencing this behaviour in Chrome. Firefox and IE both render the list report aswell as the chart report, although there is a table overlap problem in Firefox, but first things first.

Comment: I just upgraded Google Chrome to the latest version and that solved the issue. I did some research online and my results suggest that iframe content suddenly disappearing after loading is a known issue with a certain previous version of Chrome. I have no version number, but if anyone else experiences a similar issue then they should attempt to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. You should answer your own question and accept the answer, so it's easy for others to see.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I'm able to, but I currently do not have enough reputation to do so within 8 hours of submitting the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just upgraded Google Chrome to the latest version and that solved the issue. I did some research online and my results suggest that iframe content suddenly disappearing after loading is a known issue with a certain previous version of Chrome. I have no version number, but if anyone else experiences a similar issue then they should attempt to upgrade to the latest version.